# Menu Item Change on Breakpoint

Tags: menu, media-queries

On a website i'm developing, I have replaced a menu item with the logo of the company. However when using the breakpoints (menu shifts to a drop down) I'd like the logo to change to being a normal menu item like the rest, or even be able to remove it.

[Demo link](http://test.digitalsixcreative.com)

Comment: link doesn't work.

Comment: works fine for me?

Comment: For some strange reason the link is working on mobile but not on desktop.

Answer (score 0):

The link is not working on my laptop but it was working fine with my android smart phone. I use Android debugger tool to inspect your site.

You can hide the logo inside the menu with css and media queries and add another logo above the navigation and show it only on desktop.

Below css could help.

```
    @media (min-width: 800px){
        .hide_desktop { display: none;  }
    }
    @media (min-width: 801px) {
        .hide_mobile { display: none;   }
    }
```

HTML markup

```
    <div class="hide_desktop"><a href="#home"><img src="logo.png"></a></div>
    <ul class="showing">
        <li><a href="#about_anchor"><li>ABOUT</li></a></li>
        <li><a href="#work_anchor">REVIEWS</a></li>
        <li class="hide_mobile"><a href="#home"><img src="logo.png"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#services_anchor">SERVICES</a></li>
        <li><a href="#connect_anchor">CONTACT</a></li>
        &nbsp;
    </ul>
```

Comment: I don't want to add the logo 'above' the nav to be only shown on Desktop... I wan't it to be inline with the navigation when on desktop, and be able to hide it and show another link in its place while the mobile menu is on show.